# Python3 nmap script with Yes No option

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new at Python3 (and Python 2.x)
I use a lot nmap to scan my servers on regular basis to make sure the proper ports are open or closed.

My goal is to write a Python3 script with nmap for other IT people to use . I would like my script to do the following:

1. choose an option to scan

   ```
   option 1 quick scan
   option 2 most common tcp ports
   option 3 scan ports 1-6000
   ```
2. ask the user if she/he would like write the result of the scan to an output file or just run the scan and read the output from the terminal.
3. Enter the IP address to scan

I was able to write the code for 1. and 3. but i don't seem to be able write a code with the option for yes do i want an output file

```
os.system("nmap -T4 -A -v -Pn -oN outputfile.txt"+ str(ip)
```

or no I do not want an output file

```
os.system("nmap -T4 -A -v -Pn "+ str(ip)
```

I hope i was clear in my post. I would be happy to share the code that i already wrote.

Here is the code. I am sure there are mistakes. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#Library
import os, sys, time
print (sys.argv)

import subprocess

# Clear the screen
subprocess.call('clear', shell=True)

print('Welcome to ScanNmap')
print(' ')

def main():

    print('Please make your selection')
    print(' ')
    print('[1] Quick scan')
    print('[2] most common tcp ports + OS detection')
    print('[3] Scan - all TCP ports.')

    print('[9] Exit.')
    print(' ')

    option = input('Choose your Scanning Option:')


    if (option == 1):
        print('Do you want an output file?')
        answer = input()
        if answer == 'no':      
            ip = input('Input IP Address / Hostname:')
            os.system("nmap -T4 -v -Pn"+ str(ip))
            print('\n[**] Done \n')
            main()

    else answer == 'yes':
        ip = input('Input IP Address / Hostname:')
        os.system('nmap -T4  -v -Pn -oN outputfile.txt'+ str(ip)
        #print("\n[**] Done \n")
        main()  

    if (option == 2):
        print('Do you want an output file?')
        answer = input()
        if answer == 'no':      
            ip = input('Input IP Address / Hostname:')
            os.system('nmap -T4 -A -v -Pn'+ str(ip))
            print('\n[**] Done \n')
            main()

    else answer == 'yes':
        ip = input('Input IP Address / Hostname:')
        os.system('nmap -T4 -A -v -Pn -oN outputfile.txt'+ str(ip)
        print('\n[**] Done \n')
        main()

    if (option == 3):
        print('Do you want an output file?')
        answer = input()
        if answer == 'no':      
            ip = input('Input IP Address / Hostname:')
            os.system('nmap -T4 -p- -v -Pn'+ str(ip))
            print('\n[**] Done \n')
            main()

    else answer == 'yes':
        ip = input('Input IP Address / Hostname:')
        os.system('nmap -T4 -p- -v -Pn -oN outputfile.txt'+ str(ip)
        print('\n[**] Done \n')
        main()



    else:
    print("\nInvalid Option..Let's try again >>\n")
        main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()

    except KeyboardInterrupt: 
        print("\n Keyboard  has been stopped :(")
        print("\n[**] Stopping nmap scan.. Thank you for using NmapScan \n")
        time.sleep(2)
        pass
```

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to share the code you have.

Comment: I would recommend using the python-nmap library instead of using os.system. But if you want to just use system commands, you can echo the results into a file using bash.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#Library
import os, sys, time
print (sys.argv)

import subprocess

# Clear the screen
subprocess.call('clear', shell=True)

print('Welcome to ScanNmap')
print(' ')

def main():

    print('Please make your selection\n')
    print('[1] Quick scan')
    print('[2] most common tcp ports + OS detection')
    print('[3] Scan - all TCP ports.')

    print('[9] Exit.')
    print('\n')

    option = int(input('Choose your Scanning Option:'))

    print(option,type(option))
    if (option == 1):
        print('Do you want an output file?')
        answer = input()
        if answer == 'no':      
            ip = input('Input IP Address / Hostname:')
            os.system("nmap -T4 -v -Pn"+ str(ip))
            print('\n[**] Done \n')
            main()

        elif answer == 'yes':
            ip = input('Input IP Address / Hostname:')
            os.system('nmap -T4  -v -Pn -oN outputfile.txt'+ str(ip))
            print("\n[**] Done \n")
            main()  

    if (option == 2):
        print('Do you want an output file?')
        answer = input()
        if answer == 'no':      
            ip = input('Input IP Address / Hostname:')
            os.system('nmap -T4 -A -v -Pn'+ str(ip))
            print('\n[**] Done \n')
            main()

        elif answer == 'yes':
            ip = input('Input IP Address / Hostname:')
            os.system('nmap -T4 -A -v -Pn -oN outputfile.txt'+ str(ip))
            print('\n[**] Done \n')
            main()

   if (option == 3):
       print('Do you want an output file?')
       answer = input()
       if answer == 'no':      
           ip = input('Input IP Address / Hostname:')
           os.system('nmap -T4 -p- -v -Pn'+ str(ip))
           print('\n[**] Done \n')
           main()

    elif answer == 'yes':
        ip = input('Input IP Address / Hostname:')
        os.system('nmap -T4 -p- -v -Pn -oN outputfile.txt'+ str(ip))
        print('\n[**] Done \n')
        #main()

else:
    print("\nInvalid Option..Let's try again >>\n")
    #main()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
       main()

    except KeyboardInterrupt: 
        print("\n Keyboard  has been stopped :(")
        print("\n[**] Stopping nmap scan.. Thank you for using NmapScan \n")
        time.sleep(2)
        sys.exit(0)
```

I have corrected your code and I think you're not clear with your question it's better if you say how you want to scan the IPs (via file input/ dynamically). Other idea is you can use nmap library to get it done in very effective manner with less number of lines of code.

links for your ref.

[python-nmap](https://xael.org/pages/python-nmap-en.html)
[basic tcp scanner](https://github.com/alok-upadhyay/python-nmap)

Comment: Thank you for your correcting my code, i greatly appreciate it. I ran the code and i got these erros: Welcome to ScanNmap
 
Please make your selection

[1] Quick scan
[2] most common tcp ports + OS detection
[3] Scan - all TCP ports.
[9] Exit.


Choose your Scanning Option:1
1 <class 'int'>
Do you want an output file?
no
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nmapscan.py", line 81, in <module>
    main()
  File "nmapscan.py", line 32, in main
    ip = raw_input('Input IP Address / Hostname:')
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

I tried to fix but no luck

Comment: if you're using python 3 you should replace it with input()

Comment: are you still facing the issue? I can help you now.

Comment: - Thank you for your suggestion. i am learning that Python 2.3 xx and Python 3 are quite different! so problem is fixed. 
My next is, Although i entered the IP that i want to scan i have this error message.
"Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts scanned.
Nmap done: 0 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.03 seconds"
I dont see what i am doing wrong - Thanks for your help.